# Is there a way, in Android Studio to use a Style Theme Color like colorPrimary for my Item Background intsted of @color/"whateverColorYouWant"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-theme, android-color

Is there a way, in Android Studio to use a Style Theme Color like `colorPrimary` for my Item Background instead of `@color/"whateverColorYouWant"`

I would like to change the theme during the game and the colors of everything in the view. Is there a way I could assign objects a variable `@styles/colorPrimary`? This would allow me to change `@styles/colorPrimary`, causing any objects assigned this color to update. This would allow the changing of many objects at once without manually changing each object, but instead updating one variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got colorPrimary defined in a theme, you can access it in XML via `?colorPrimary` in the same way you'd put @color/whateverColor.  The question mark (?) represents a reference to a themed attribute.  If you're using the pre-existing Android attribute, though, you will want to use `?android:colorPrimary`. You can add your own attributes that you can reference this way in your `attrs.xml` file. If you need to access the themed elements by code, this is one way to do it:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
boolean success = getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimary, value, true);
int color = value.data;
```